# Yahoo Answers API - questionSearch - Filter out certain words

Tags: api, url, rest, yahoo

Is the Yahoo Answers API very limited on its functionality, or the documentation is incomplete?

Here is API ref:
http://developer.yahoo.com/answers/V1/questionSearch.html

I'd need to be able to retrieve questions that contain termA or termB but neither termC or termD.

Example URL for questions containing termA:
http://answers.yahooapis.com/AnswersService/V1/questionSearch?appid=YahooDemo&query=termA

Also, further information on the API will be helpful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some Googling showed that the `query` supports AND, OR, ANDNOT and brackets. So for a query that returns anything on cats but nothing on dogs:

`http://answers.yahooapis.com/AnswersService/V1/questionSearch?appid=YahooDemo&query=cats+ANDNOT+dogs`

As for the brackets, to query for anything that mentions cats or dogs but not fish:

`http://answers.yahooapis.com/AnswersService/V1/questionSearch?appid=YahooDemo&query=(cats+dogs)+ANDNOT+fish`

Comment: Can you get me the link from where you got that? I'd like to have a look at it.